# App's NSExtension crash at launch in Release build

Tags: swift, crash, crash-reports, appkit

I'm developing an app extension using Apple's Workflow_Extensions_SDK_1.0.1. Everything works in Debug mode but after Archiving and exporting the extension crashes at launch. The container app is working fine but the extension crashes all the time.

No need to provide any code samples since the crash log has only system calls, not a single call to my code base. Basically, the crashed stack is this:

```
Crashed Thread:        2  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCListener.service.com.cinetagonist.my-app.extension.apple-extension-service
    
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [6513]
        
Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCListener.service.com.my-app.extension.apple-extension-service
        0   com.apple.ExtensionKit          0x00007fff31be0386 __58+[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor _extensionContextClass]_block_invoke.cold.1 + 38
        1   com.apple.ExtensionKit          0x00007fff31bd2fa0 __58+[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor _extensionContextClass]_block_invoke + 195
        2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff204877c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2048896b _dispatch_once_callout + 20
        4   com.apple.ExtensionKit          0x00007fff31bd2edb +[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor _extensionContextClass] + 42
        5   com.apple.ExtensionKit          0x00007fff31bd3126 -[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor listener:shouldAcceptNewConnection:] + 59
        6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21538462 service_connection_handler_make_connection + 162
        7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff20375c28 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 56
        8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff20374cd5 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1504
        9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20487867 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 9
        10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2049ea47 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 441
        11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2048d4a7 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 263
        12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2049f5b8 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 498
        13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2048d4a7 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 263
        14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2048e0fe _dispatch_lane_invoke + 426
        15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20497c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2062f499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2062e467 start_wqthread + 15
```

I've filed a bug report, asking Apple for help. But a week have passed and no answer received. So, I'm asking for help here.

The documentation on Workflow Extension SDK is very limited. Have read it a bazilliion times already )

Maybe someone had such errors and have found a solution?

**UPDATE:**

I've created a blank Swift project and added a blank workflow extension target. Same thing: the extension works in Debug and crashes in Release.

Then I've created a blank Objective-C project with a blank extension. And now the extension runs perfectly in Release mode.

So, the issue is definitely in Swift/ObjC interoperability. But I still stuck on finding the exact code that produces the crash since there's not much code in the blank project.

The PrincipalViewControllerClass key in the Info.plist is prefixed with module name, so that's not the issue.

Have tried adding @objc(class_name) to swift classes. But still nothing.

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:**
Had to switch the PrincipalViewController (the one that is loading at launch) to Objective-C. Don't know why but the Workflow Extension SDK simply doesn't load an NSViewController subclass written in Swift in Release mode. Guess, it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Apple, the reason for that crashes in Release mode was identified.
In Workflow Extension there's a required string property hostInfo in the Extension main view controller. It needs to be prefixed with @objc in Swift.